# Jsch "exec" channel does not close automatically after executing long running command

Tags: java, session, inputstream, jsch, channel

I am running a command through JSch, which just executes a script and which has a command that performs some operation for a long time.

---

The scenario is that the script has a command that does not print its output to the console rather it appends it to some file.
This command takes a long time (More than 1 hour) without printing anything to the console.

---

The issue now is that the command and the script are completed (Checked in the server file in which output is printed) but nothing gets printed on the console and the channel is also not closed which is my exit condition thus resulting in a **hang state** since there is no command to execute and channel is not closed.

Please find code snippet below:

```
channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(error_stream, true);
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);       
channel.connect(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0) {
            break;
        }
        print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        print("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ee) {
        logger.error(ee.toString());
    }
}
channel.disconnect();
```

I need to find out why the channel is not being closed.

Note:

1. After the successful command execution is completed, the session is not present on Server -- checked using **ps fx**
2. This issue is only reproducible when the command runs without consoling to the output for at least an hour

---

Sample command:

```
echo "start"
sleep 3700s
echo "end"
touch endFile.sh
```

In the above script, the "start is printed to the console, but "end" is not printed, however the endFile.sh is created on the server, indicating the execution is complete

Comment: Could you provide an example of the actual command that you're executing? What does it do? Does it create any additional subprocesses which continue to run after the main process exits?

Comment: The command example is just running as basic script ex: ./testScript.sh. the content in which varies. Out of the 4-5 times, I have observed the issue, sometimes it was an internal command which used to run java jar and other a DML SQL statement executed using sqlplus.

Comment: Only common factor when this issue occurred was the time taken which was at least an hour

Comment: yes, the problem is reproducible with sleep. I put in a sleep command for just more than an hour. After the sleep time, there was no process present of JSch on the server but it did not break out of the loop.

Comment: Done. Any Solution /Suggestion?

Comment: Hi @UtkarshAgrawal have you got any solution for this. I am also getting this issue for long running commands

Comment: @Jugi No haven't got any solution for this until now.

Comment: One observation I made, was that this issue only occurs when my Linux instance is hosted on AWS as an EC2 instance. I tried the same thing by creating a new Linux instance locally, the issue did not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, working for me

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");


      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);


      channel.setInputStream(null);

      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      //To print the result on the console using below 3 line

      byte[] bytes = command.getBytes();   //To print the result
      ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);//To print the result
      channel.setInputStream(bais);//To print the result

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();



      channel.connect();
     channel.setOutputStream(System.out);//To print the result
      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```